# how to colate a list of installed packages into a "one-liner" for re-installing later (using only grep / cut / sed / awk etc, no external tools)

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, cut

**Command:**
`apt list --installed`

**Output:**

```sh
aapt/stable,now 7.1.2.33-7 aarch64 [installed]
abduco/stable,now 0.6-2 aarch64 [installed]
ack-grep/stable,now 3.3.1 all [installed]
antibody/stable,now 6.0.1 aarch64 [installed]
apt/stable,now 1.4.9-27 aarch64 [installed]
```

**I would like:**

`aapt abduco ack-grep antibody apt`

**Therefore I need:**

Only up-to the first `/` in the first field, but shown in one line, not multiple.

**Background info:**

- I would like to backup a list of installed packages,
- But only the name of the package, nothing else,
- Shown on one line.

This list can then be appended with `sudo apt install` to make a quick one-liner for re-installing my packages later on, once I have wiped my system.

Comment: Hi! What have you tried?

Comment: `dpkg-query` with `-f` option might be useful https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/344864

Comment: `dpkg-query -f '${Package} ' -W` also works! **THANK YOU** for pointing me to this @user13651875 !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you:
`apt list --installed | awk -F'/' '{print $1}' | tr '\n' ' '`

`apt list --installed` list the packages.
`awk -F'/' '{print $1}'` take the first column using / as separator.
`tr '\n' ' '` replace the jump lines for spaces.

Comment: Welcome to SO, request you to please so wrap your codes/samples in CODE TAGS, cheers and happy learning on forums.

Comment: Nice answer! Both your answer (using awk) and the answer from @Francesco Lucianó (using cut & sed) produce the perfect output! I prefer your answer though as you included an explanation for the commands, which helps me understand better, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)

```
$ apt list --installed | awk -F/ '{s=$1" "s} END{print s}' 
apt antibody ack-grep abduco apt antibody ack-grep abduco aapt
```

Comment: This also works, but provides the list backwards (Z-A not A-Z) this is not a problem so still a correct answer! Thank you @SiegeX

Answer (score 1):

With `cut` and `tr`:

```
apt list --installed | cut -f1 -d / | tr "\n" " "
```

With sed:

```
apt list --installed | sed -E ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g;s/\/[^]]+\]//g'
```

I think the first one is more readable and easier to understand.

Comment: They **both** give me the perfect output!  They will save me alot of time!! **THANK YOU!**